# How to put links into words?

Tags: support

When I want to answer a question, I have difficulties putting a link into a word so that when a person wants to go to a website encrypted into the word, all they have to do is click it. I've seen other users doing it, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone give me directions?

Comment: ok who downvoted?

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean people generally 'dislike' the question. Don't worry about it, there's no rep penalty. In this case, I think whomever downvoted probably did so becase this is a fairly trivial thing.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To type them manually, use `[text](link)`.

Alternatively, use the link button shown below:

[image: The link icon is circled]

Which will put them in markdown like so:

```
[The link][1]

<Your text>

  [1]: http://www.google.com.au
```

In future, you can check out the formatting help or click the question mark in the upper right.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. Now I know how to do this.

Comment: @JerryRox - If Yuki's answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted